# How to add the Cover image of your iOS App in the App store

Tags: ios, app-store

[image]

As, shown in the picture the picture a cover image of instagram app has displayed but on most of the app we have not seen this. So how can i add this kind of cover image in my app for app store

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Only featured apps can have customized cover image or header. These applications are selected by Apple. This isn't a setting that we can control.

Here is an article on how to get featured in the App Store:
https://thenextweb.com/dd/2013/10/29/get-featured-app-store/

Comment: Is it still the same? Does only featured apps can have cover image?

Answer (score 7):

Apple selects popular apps and allows them to add the Cover Photo and Themes. It isn't upto the developers.

From official confirmation on this:

> Applications that have custom background art on the App Store are selected editorially by Apple. If your application is selected to be receive custom art, you will be contacted by an Apple representative.